# I need a simple way in python that prevents a first name or last name to be part of a password inputed

Tags: python, input, names

If I ask the user to input their first name and their last name I need the password that is inputed to not include the first and last name. I also need a simple way to do this not very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Easy :)

```
password = "thisJaKob"
firstname = "jakOB"
lastname = "Bowyer"

test_pass = password.lower()
if (firstname.lower() in test_pass) or (lastname.lower() in test_pass):
    print "Idiot. don't use names in passwords."
```

Because strings are immutable they support the `in` operator, which checks if the left hand side is a valid sub-string in the right hand side.